# Difference between probe_success and up?

Tags: prometheus

What's the difference between `probe_success` and `up`?

I see various examples where alerting is done based on either of them (eg. site down, instance down). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`up` indicates whether Prometheus could talk to and successfully scrape a target, such as the blackbox exporter.

`probe_success` is a metric exposed by the blackbox exporter indicating if a probe succeeded.

For alerting you need both, as if the blackbox exporter is down or timing out then that's indicated by `up` and if the probe itself is failing that'll be indicated by `probe_success`.

Comment: Still confused a little. The node_exporter shows up/down but doesn't have a probe_success. If i'm writing my own exporter should I implement both?

Comment: This is covered by https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/#failed-scrapes